# How to do a proper quaternion transformation?

Tags: c++

I have some code which transforms a transformation on quaternions and works. But it is written pretty badly, does someone know how to write this better/shorter and does someone knows, if this entire transformation is a transformation 90 degrees on y in euler angles?

Edit: I get a quaternion (orix, oriy, oriz, oriw), then I use this transformation, which should be -pi/2 around y (but I am not sure), then I got the output quaternion. There is no code missing, this code functions as it is here. (of course with the right imports, tf2.

```
            tf2::Quaternion quat(orix, -oriy, oriz, oriw);
            tf2::Quaternion q_rot;
            tf2::Vector3 rotation_vector(0.7071068, 0, 0.7071068);
            q_rot.setRotation(rotation_vector, M_PI);
            quat = q_rot*quat;
            quat.normalize();   
            tf2::Matrix3x3 matrix(quat);
            tf2::Matrix3x3 change_y(1,0, 0, 0, -1,0 ,0 ,0, 1);
            matrix = change_y * matrix;

            double roll, pitch, yaw;
            matrix.getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
            quat.setRPY(roll,pitch,yaw);`
```

Comment: If you're not sure if/how this code does what it should, we can't help you. On top of that, there's a lot of code missing that's essential context for a proper review. In it's current state, we can't help you with this question.

Comment: Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].